# Can't include bootstrap from resources

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to include bootstrap files from resources in jsp, but for some reason it doesn't work(styles aren't applied to HTML elements). Header of my view looks like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- authentication.jsp -->
        <!--  this works
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
              crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

        <!--this doesn't work-->
        <link href="<c:url value="/webapp/resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--................-->
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my folder structure:

[image]

And this is my AppConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.gtu.gtesting"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already declare `resourceHandler` for it. So just do like below in `.jsp`

```
<link href="resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This should work.If it doesn't work for you, try this

```
<link href="<c:url value='resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or all full path

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Edited the answer. You can try those to make it work for you.

Comment: I have tried them too and they don't work. this is link of my project on github: [project](https://github.com/AlexDev5/gtesting)